# C++: Is there a way to define each element of a 2-D array as such:

Tags: c++, arrays

So I was wondering if there is a way  to define each element of a 2-D array similar to how you would define elements of a one dimensional array:

`int Array[3] = {2, 3, 4, 5};`

If I had a two-dimensional array like:

`int Array[3][3]`

Is there a way to manually enter the values of the elements like I did above with the single array? I am aware that this is would not be the most effective method, but I need to try it this way to test a small amount of values to make sure my program is working properly.

Thank you!

Comment: `int Array[3][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very simple dear. It goes like this :-

```
int a[][3] { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} };
```

This creates a `2 X 3` 2D array. In `multidimensional arrays` you needn't mention the dimension in the first `[]` but it's compulsory to mention the same in the rest. For ex this is wrong :-

```
int a[3][] = // whatever ;
```

So there you go !!